# What does @model do in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

i am trying to learn .NET and I am following a tutorial and in it, it has this at the top of the index.cshtml page:

```
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

    <h2>It's @Model.Time right now on the server!</h2>
```

What do the top two lines do? And why is it referenced using "Model" and not "model", I cannot find any info on this online.

Comment: Here you go: [Razor syntax reference for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@page` and `@model` are two directives, while `@Model` is referencing the Model object on the page.

The `@page` tells asp.net this is a page, while `@model` tells it what your model class is, in this case it's `IndexModel` class.

You can find more info on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio